# Make a sentence from the term "computer literacy"

Tags: grammaticality

Is it okay for me to write “having computer literacy”, since the word *literacy* is a noun?

Comment: What are you trying to convey?

Comment: Being computer literate, . . .

Comment: yes it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

> We would like all students in our school to achieve basic computer
>   literacy by the end of third grade.

--- Edit ---

I read your question more carefully.  I have a problem with *having.*  But if I change that word, and consider **to have computer literacy**, I would say, it's not *wrong*, but it's not mellifluous, and it would be better to say **to be computer literate**.

Answer (score 0):

*To be computer literate* and *to have computer literacy* are both accepted when the first is strongly preferred.